# rendering on Standard account Layout workaround.?

Tags: apex, standard-objects, customization

I have a picklist field Status on account.There are 3 values One,Two,Other.

IF Other is selected i need a text field to show so that user can enter some information.I know thats not possible on standard layout.

Is it possible i can make that text field non-editable if Other value is selected..?

Can someone suggest me a possible workaround for this.??

Thanks

Comment: Likely will need VF for this, but not sure as I don't fully understand the question.  You say you want to show a text field if other is selected, but in the next sentence say you want it to be read only if other is selected.

Comment: Hi...i want if any of this is possible. Either rendering text field or May be make it is un-editable when value is selected other than "Other".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this in a supported way on the standard page layouts.  It is possible using JavaScript embedded into an HTML area on a sidebar component that adds an onchange handler to the picklist element that adds/removes a handler on the text box - for example, adding an onfocus event that executes a blur to stop the user being able to click into it.

This is fragile as Salesforce do not support it and could block this at any time, breaking your interface.

Using purely standard capabilities the best you can do is to add some help text to explain the rules and enforce them via a validation rule.

Otherwise you are looking at Visual Flow to guide the user based on their selection or Visualforce to dynamically update the page either via the JavaScript method outlined above or a round trip to the server.

Comment: Can you explain how can we achieve using JavaScript embedded into an HTML area on a sidebar component?? Can you please provide any link or detail..Thanks

Comment: There's an example of using sidebar javascript to hide a button on this page: http://www.tehnrd.com/show-and-hide-buttons-on-page-layouts/